# Databinding issue when hosted in winform usercontrol

Tags: wpf

I had a fine working wpf control which hosted several other wpf controls.  Now I imported all wpf studd into new project and use that project now as a reference to display main wpf user control in winform user control (as before, only wpf controls, viewmodels etc are in separate assembly/project).

I don't know why, but it seems that databinding fails now below 1st level: top level is displayed, but the rest (details in other controls) is not displayed (no controls).  Also I have couple of images on the bottom of wpf control whic aren't displayed either.  Their sources are bound to corresponding properties in ViewModel.

I spent about 5 hours and can't figure out what could be the problem.

Any suggestions?

Also, I put a breakpoint on get property for the image source in my ViewModel, but it never hits.

Comment: Sorry I have no Idea, I've done this before without a hitch. You really need to give us some of the code, like an example of the binding and also how you are using the control if we are going to make any headway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you've changed how one of the DataContext properties on your control gets set.  If you check the output window during debug execution, you should see all of the bindings that fail, and I'd expect to see the image source on your viewmodel to be one of them.  Check that the DataContext on the child controls is being set correctly.

Without any code references, it is hard to determine where that error might be.